# How avoid Ghost clones with jQuery accordion ko.bindingHandlers

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, knockout.js

I have two accordions bound with ko.observableArrays and want to move items between them.
The observableArrays are updated correctly, but somehow the elements I move are duplicated when received by the target-accordion.

Here´s the bindingHandlers:

```
(function () {
ko.bindingHandlers.jqAccordion = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor) {
        var options = valueAccessor();
        $(element).accordion(options);
        $(element).bind("valueChanged", function () {
            ko.bindingHandlers.jqAccordion.update(element, valueAccessor);
        });

        ko.utils.domNodeDisposal.addDisposeCallback(element, function () {
            $(element).accordion("destroy");
        });
    },
    update: function (element, valueAccessor) {
        var options = valueAccessor();

        $(element).accordion("destroy").accordion({
            header: ".accordion-header",
            collapsible: true,
            navigation: true,
            heightStyle: "content",
            active: false
        })
        .sortable({
            axis: "x,y",
            handle: ".accordion-header",
            placeholder: "ui-state-highlight",
            connectWith: "div",
            start: function (event, ui) {
                sorting = true;
                //find what tab is open, false if none
                active = $(this).accordion("option", "active");
                //possibly change animation here (to make the animation instant if you like)
                $(element).accordion("option", "animate", {
                    easing: 'swing',
                    duration: 0
                });
                //close tab
                $(element).accordion({
                    active: false
                });
            },
            over: function (event, ui) {
                $(element).accordion({
                    active: false
                });
            },
            stop: function (event, ui) {
                //1st: Handle the visible impression during sorting...
                // IE doesn't register the blur when sorting so trigger focusout handlers to remove .ui-state-focus
                ui.item.children("h3").triggerHandler("focusout");
                $(element).accordion("option", "animate", {});
                active = false;
                $(element).accordion("option", "active", active);
                sorting = false;
                //2nd: Create sequence listing of items for later saving
                var items = [], itemSeqNos = [];
                ui.item.siblings().andSelf().each(function () {
                    if ($(this).data('index') != $(this).index()) {
                        items.push(this.id);
                        itemSeqNos.push(this.id.replace("scene", ""));
                    }
                });
                ui.item.parent().trigger('stop');
            },
            receive: function (event, ui) {
                var source = ui.sender.context.id;
                var draggedId = ui.item[0].id.replace("scene", "");
                var target = this.id;
                if (target !== source) { // unless dropped on it self.
                    var context = ko.contextFor(this);
                    if (context) {
                        context.$root.rearrangeArrays(draggedId, target, source);
                    }
                }
            }
        })
        .on({
            stop: function () {
                $(this).siblings().andSelf().each(function (i) {
                    $(this).data('index', i);
                });
            }
        })
        .trigger('stop')
        .draggable({
            handle: ".accordion-header",
            helper: 'original',
            revert: true,
            revertDuration: 0,
            cursor: 'default',
            connectWith: options.target
        }).disableSelection();
    }
};
})();
```

The update of the observableArrays are done in the rearrangeArrays-function where I 
push the "draggedId"-item onto the "target" and remove it from the "source".

The dropped/received item is duplicated even if the draggable helper is set to 'original' (instead of 'clone').

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/AsleG/cnLftvhe/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to a problem with the way knockout reads templates combined with the templating engine in use - but it has a simple workaround.  You just need to remove whitespace from outside your top level template node:

```
<script type="text/html" id="scene-template"><div data-bind="attr: {'id': 'scene' + sceneID}" class="ui-widget-content"> 
        <div class="accordion-header ui-widget-header" > 
            <span data-bind="text:sceneID"></span>
            <span data-bind="text:title"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="ui-widget-content">
            <span data-bind="text:text"></span>
        </div >                    
    </div></script>
```

ie the `div` now starts and ends right next to the `script` opening and closing tags.  The duplicate still shows while the alerts are displayed, but once execution can continue, knockout cleans up properly and leaves you with just the one rendered template.

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kj0xLm3n/)

Comment: Thanx, James! This fix the fiddle. In my working project however, the items are still duplicated. Any ideas to how I can approach that?
Would it be other issues also causing this, like comments or the fact that I´m running my code as a module in Dotnetnuke?

Comment: @Asle Not sure - when I've seen the problem in the past (has occurred to me & my colleagues at least 3 times separately in different areas), it was always fixed by ensuring absolutely no whitespace outside the root element

Comment: Would there be any other work around for this? For instant handling this by coding in the bindingHandlers?

Comment: I have now verified my projects problem is due to Dotnetnukes formatting of HTML. Even if I remove whitespaces from outside top level temp ate node, DNN is breaking the line after the first div.

I really do not know what to do with this….

Comment: @Asle Could you put the template in a manual external html file, and download it dynamically before running the bindings?  We load templates this way in our app, just use jQuery `load` to load the html templates into a div, then call `applyBindings` in the success callback.  So long as you can get it loaded into the client without DNN touching it, it should be ok

Comment: Sounds like a possible solution. So I replace the <script type="text/html" id="scene-template">…</script>
with something like <div id="template-replace"> and then in the   jQuery(document).ready() do a 
$("#template-replace").load("scene-template.txt").success( ko.applyBinding(viewModel);  ?

Should this replace the original ko.applyBinding or come in addition?

Comment: @Asle Yep.  In our case, the `???` in `success` is just a call to `ko.applyBindings`

Comment: Hmm. I can get it to load, but the <div id="template-replace"> node remains and the html from the load still has a CRLF after the <script> node...

Comment: I found a solution based upon the knockout-sortable.js that´s working in my project. However it isn´t working in the fiddle ;) Take a look if you care: http://jsfiddle.net/AsleG/kj0xLm3n/1/

Comment: @Asle I see an error in the fiddle - `Cannot read property 'afterAdd' of undefined` - is this what you meant by not working?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67488/discussion-between-asle-g-and-james-thorpe).

Answer (score 0):

I found that Dotnetnuke which is the framework for my project broke up the top node as the suggested fix by James Thorpe. James´ suggestion worked well in the fiddle and also the jQuery.load-suggestion was a creative approach. To bad Dnn didn´t fall for that. ;)

In the end I made a close approach to Ryan Niemeyers knockout-sortable.js and came up with a working solution. It can be found here: http //jsfiddle.net/AsleG/7zyfs5nt/

Thanx for all the help and Merry Xmas!